# EFCodeFirst CTP 5 won't populate the model with any records - the queries run fine however

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I'm using the EFCodeFirst package with the MVCMusicStore sample application.

Everything worked fine when I was using the SQL Express database. However, after creating the DB in SQL Server 2008 and updating the connection string, all my queries return 0 records. SQL Profiler shows that the queries run, and I can copy the query into SSMS and it returns rows.

Here's a query and my connection string:

var genres = storeDb.Genres.ToList(); (returns a count of 0)

add name="MusicStoreEntities" connectionString="Data Source=.;initial catalog=MvcMovieStore;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Any thoughts on this behavior? It obviously connects to the database and executes the query which I can see in SQL Profiler.

Comment: So is the model being populated with records or not - it is not clear if you can populate but not read, or neither populate nor read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the query runs in SSMS and returns rows, but no rows are returned in your app, it must be that your app is not working against the same DB instance.  I had the exact same situation when moving from SQL CE to Express.

What i ended up doing was connecting to the DB from the application, using the servers tab, and then copying the connection string.

Comment: I had a typo in the initial catalog name of the connection string. I guess since the connection succeeded and a query was executed, EF created a new DB on the fly since one didn't exist with that name?

Comment: Yes, that is what must have been happening.  All that behind the scenes goodness sometimes turns around and bites you...

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in the name of the machine as for Data Source ... Data Source=MYMACHINE